# Não consigo configurar corretamento as variaveis de ambiente para android para usar o Ionic

Tags: android, ionic

estou iniciando em mobile e to fazendo a configuração para o Ionic. Bom a minha dificuldade está sendo na hora de executar `sudo cordova run android`  que me retorna:

```
  Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined
  (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
  Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android
  Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please
  include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Meu bashrc está assim:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulato
```

Possa ser que eu esteja esquecendo de alguma outra configuração ou até mesmo fazendo isso em um lugar errado, gostaria da ajuda de vocês. se alguem tiver algumas dicas ou ate mesmo o passo a passo agradeceria!

Comment: a princípio o ANDROID_SDK_ROOT está configurado corretamente... pode tentar também um export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk . De toda forma, o jeito mais fácil de fazer essa configuração é instalando o Android Studio porque ele já instala tudo... Você está com o JDK configurado?

Comment: @brenodiogo sim sim, mas hoje anoite vou fazer isso de novo. fiquei sem fazer isso esses dias.